# Is there an Oracle C Client for OpenVMS on Integrity

Tags: c, oracle, client, openvms

I have a legacy system, which I'd like to migrate to a more modern architecture. As a start I'd like to migrate the database layer, but I can't seem to find a C Client for OpenVMS.

On the [Oracle Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) this architecture isn't listed, but I found forum entries, where there is talk about an official C Client. Of course there is [OCILIB](http://orclib.sourceforge.net/), which say the can run on OpenVMS, but don't provide an installation script or any standard way to install this library, and I don't know how to transform the make file to an DCL script or sth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For anyone googling this question here ist the answer:
Yes, there is an implementation of the Oracle OCI-Library, but you have to order it with the client CD. You can then install OCILIB over this Library, but you have to do your own DCL script.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you should file a Service Request with Oracle Support - ask for the Midrange Team (OpenVMS specialists)

Comment: You might also consider precompilers. The precompiler for C is "Pro*C" - much easier to use than native OCI calls. You have some reading to do if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the data now? RMS (indexed) files? Are the data-layer calls already isolated in functions? From experience: if the legacy app is using inline file IO like Cobol START/READ/WRITE/REWRITE it will be near impossible to replace.

Anyway,  You can NOT just grab an OCILIB (like a  libclntsh.exe)  library and use. There is however a full Oracle client with OCILIB and sundry which you can download and just install'.
Note: It is a big kit, perhaps 90% of the full DB install kit. Please explain why / how that kit is not working for you (after reading its docs). No 'make' file should be needed.

So you intend to call Oracle using C modules on OpenVMS Integrity? That should be fine.

Any further specific version info? OpenVMS integrity 8.4? (not too critical). Legacy Language used? Target Oracle version / platform?

Good luck!